Android studio en archivo java NO me deja escribir
a ver si alquien me salva
Estuve practicando un poco con las keymap y no se que toque que ahora no puedo escribir, o sea,
si el cursor esta en la linea 1 y me voy con el mouse a la linea 10(x ejem), me pinta el bloque entre esas lineas

Prueba restableciendo la configuración del IDE. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65044920
